# Image change when hovered over?

Tags: javascript, css, hover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change image on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468085/change-image-on-mouseover)

Can anyone tell me how I could get pic1_s to pic9_s images in the following code to change to a different pic when they are hovered over? I have different versions of each picture which are darkened with an opacity layer and have writing. They already have a jquery lightbox effect on them and a carousel effect. Can find here: http://www.meanbeangames.com/ (under the main image three abreast).

```
    <div class="image_carousel">
            <div id="foo2">
                <a href="img/pic1_b.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Death From Above">
                    <img src="img/pic1_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>
                <a href="img/pic2_b.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Tree Under Attack">
                    <img src="img/pic2_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>
                <a href="img/pic3_b.jpg" id="pic3" rel="gallery" title="World Map">
                    <img src="img/pic3_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>
                <a href="img/pic4_b.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Combo Attack">
                    <img src="img/pic4_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>
                <a href="img/pic5_b.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Robots Strike">
                    <img src="img/pic5_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>
                <a href="img/pic6_b.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Back Stab">
                    <img src="img/pic6_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>
                <a href="img/pic7_b.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Critical Hit">
                    <img src="img/pic7_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>
                <a href="img/pic8_b.jpg" rel="gallery" title="All Out War">
                    <img src="img/pic8_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>
                <a href="img/pic9_b.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Air Defense">
                    <img src="img/pic9_s.jpg" class="fancy_thumb" width="320" height="198" />
                </a>

            </div>

            <a class="prev" id="foo2_prev" href="#"><span>prev</span></a>

            <a class="next" id="foo2_next" href="#"><span>next</span></a>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

set them as a background image for the `<a>`:

And on hover switch them.

```
a:link, a:visited {
  display: block;
  background: url(image-light.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  width: width of image;
  height: height of image;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  background-image: url(image-dark.jpg);
}
```